# how to observe if variable changes value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, observers

I know of `Object.observe()` and Object.`prototype.watch()` but those are not very widely suported features (unfortunatly), meanwhile I know AngularJS does something to watch changes on objects...

I'm trying to create an script with this capability but much much lighter than Angular. First I remembered that I saw somewhere in this site that object properties could have (or had) set and get methods. That sounded strange to me maybe my memory is weak.

Am I in the right direction? Any enlightment on how to do this?

Comment: What do you want to watch? An object?

Comment: https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few polyfils for observing variable value, I've been using this one

https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583